# Google Sheet use filters to sort with Unique

Tags: google-sheets

In google sheet, I have a data set A:

[image]

In another sheet I am creating a dynamic list using the UNIQUE formula:
[image]

However, when I use filters to sort the data, it gets all scattered leaving empty cells where there shouldn't be any:

[image]

Does anyone know a workaround to avoid this? Is it impossible to use filters AND Unique at the same time or is there another way to do this?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to use the UI filters to filter the result of formulas like UNIQUE that return an array of values, instead you could use the built-in function [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en), i.e. `=SORT(UNIQUE(A1:B6,1)` among other alternatives (pivot table, Google Apps Script, copy-paste as values, then sort, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Use a pivot table, and sort it by sumof column2 instead of the unique + sumif combination that you are using. See this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oaU_pX8KfKKUD4oNN95Z2Lv8WFZMlxnsFrqy-K3rEHw/edit?usp=sharing) to see it working on your data.